# Character vector to ellipsis input

Tags: r, rlang

I have the following function which takes an unquoted input and returns a character vector of the input objects.

```
my_function <- function(...) {

  v_chr <- purrr::map_chr(rlang::enexprs(...), rlang::as_name)
  v_chr

}

my_function(apple, orange)
```

```
"apple" "orange"
```

I am trying to build a wrapper around it that takes a character vector input. This does not work.

```
my_wrapper <- function(v_chr) {

  x <- rlang::syms(v_chr) 
  my_function(x)

}

v_chr <- c("apple", "orange")
my_wrapper(v_chr)
```

```
"x"
```

**Question**

1. How to I get `my_wrapper()` to return the same output as `my_function()`?
2. BONUS: Is there a more streamlined way to achieve the results in `my_function()`?

I would like the solution to use `rlang`, but would not mind seeing the base solution in addition.

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/evaluating-using-rlang-when-supplying-a-vector/44693/10) on the RStudio Community, part of a discussion of a function that can take both bare symbols and character vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper should look like

```
my_wrapper <- function(v_chr) {      
  x <- rlang::syms(v_chr) 
  rlang::eval_tidy(my_function(!!!x))      
}
```

you need to inject those symbols into the call with the bang-bang-bang operator and then evaluate that with `eval_tidy` because "normal" R functions don't recognize `!!!`.